# C program not giving correct output

Tags: c

I have the following code which ask user to input a positive number of day(s) and it then ask user to enter the highest and lowest temperature that day, but after compiling the code when I run I the program it asks for number of day(s) it asks for highest temperature and then it just ends the program without asking for lowest temp and condition. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    int days,condt;
    double high,low,aver;

    printf("Weather Analyzer \n");
    printf("================ \n");

    printf("Please enter a positive number of days:");
    scanf("%d", &days);



    if (days <= 0) {

            while (days <= 0) {
                    printf("Please enter a positive number of days:");
                    scanf("%d", &days);
            }
    }



    printf("Enter today's high:");
    scanf("%.2f", &high);

    printf("Enter today's low:");
    scanf("%.2f", &low);

    printf("Enter today's condition: (s: sunny, c: cloudy, p: precipitation");
    scanf("%d", &condt);

    aver = high + low / 2.0;

    printf("Today's average temperature is: %.2f", aver);

}
```

This is the exact output:

```
Weather Analyzer
================
Please enter a positive number of days:3
Enter today's high:1
Enter today's low:Enter today's condition: (s: sunny, c: cloudy, p: precipitationToday's average temperature is: -0.00admin@machine:~/cprogram/weather>
```

Comment: `"%.2f"` --> `"%lf"`, `char condt;scanf(" %c", &condt);`

Comment: Oh I didn't realize I need put "%.2f" when I am printing my final result which is the average. Silly mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `high` and `low` are `double`. Change `"%.2f"` in `scanf` to `"%lf"` . For proper functionality, declare `condt` as a char. Then you can get 's' or 'c' values by using `" %c"` in `scanf`.

If you choose to use `condt` as `int` then use 1 or 2 to specify the conditions like :

```
 printf("Enter today's condition: (1: sunny, 2: cloudy, 3: precipitation");
```

then check the conditions and do calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    int days;
    char condt;
    double high,low,aver;

    printf("Weather Analyzer \n");
    printf("================ \n");

    printf("Please enter a positive number of days:");
    scanf("%d", &days);



    if (days <= 0) {

            while (days <= 0) {
                    printf("Please enter a positive number of days:");
                    scanf("%d", &days);
            }
    }



    printf("Enter today's high:");
    scanf("%lff", &high);

    printf("Enter today's low:");
    scanf("%lff", &low);

    printf("Enter today's condition: (s: sunny, c: cloudy, p: precipitation");
    scanf(" %c", &condt);

    aver = high + low / 2.0;

    printf("Today's average temperature is: %llf \n", aver);
    system("pause");
}
```